# Setting the Visibility of a Grid layout from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE upon button press

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

How can I set the visibility of a grid layout from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE in android studio.

Look at this what i'd tried-

```
public void verifyOTP(View view){      //verifyOTP is button onclick method

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    gridLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

This doesn't worked for me. i.e. when i press the verifyOTP button, the layout is not reset to VISIBLE from INVISIBLE.
please suggest some solution.